# How to add Docusign signature tab to pdf uploaded as a composite template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have an envelope created with a single request using compositeTemplates. I want to add a signature Tab to the document "test.pdf" found in the 2nd compositeTemplate.  I tried using transformPdfFields=true, shown below, and added the text "eSignSignHere" in the place where I want the signature Tab to be located in the document.  The transformation did not occur.  I'm further confused why an "initials" Tab was added at the bottom of the first page of my document.  There is no text at this location to be transformed or interpreted.  Perhaps that problem with go away when this problem is solved.

Here is the request:

```
{
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                            "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "tabs": {
                                "dateTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "value": "1-21-1974",
                                        "documentId": null,
                                        "selected": null
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "3093E017-2E18-4A30-A104-0201C601CE5F"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                            "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "tabs": {
                                "dateTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "value": "1-21-1974",
                                        "documentId": null,
                                        "selected": null
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "test.pdf",
            "transformPdfFields": true
        }
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "63CA2E24-BBB8-499F-A884-021580DF54AF"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "name": "Jon D. Doe",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Proposed Insured",
                            "clientUserId": "jond@gmail.com",
                            "tabs": {
                                "dateTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "DOB",
                                        "name": null,
                                        "value": "1-21-1974",
                                        "documentId": null,
                                        "selected": null
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your PDF that you're using too (if it doesn't contain information that can't be shared).

Comment: How do I attach a document to the question?

Comment: host it on a site somewhere and just link it. if you convert it to PDFBytes, you can post it here in your question

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Andrew .. I'm working directly with docusign support on this now and it's highly likely that the contents or the way we are generating the pdf is the issue.  We'll be looking at ways that we can generate the doc that will work in concert with the way we are using the API.  I'll repost when I find the answer.

Comment: In second composite template, you have both ServerTemplate and Document inside Inline Template, do you want to load the document from both in this composite template?